# How to get the clicked event of a wpf data grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with programmaticaly added rows (items) by adding an `ItemSource`.
I do not want the user to edit the cells so I set `IsReadOnly = true;`.
But I want them to click on cells and output which cell was clicked.

I was searching for a Clicked event and was surprised there is no such event for a DataGrid. I want a behaviour like buttons where it doesn't matter if it's clicked by the mouse, space bar, enter or whatever else the system accepts as a "Click".

So how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever is in the cell template (TextBlock, for instance) could be styled to handle the PreviewMouseUp event and pull the information you want from the control or bound object.  The click event is specific to Button, TextBox and other controls that deal with mouse capture.  Here is a link that discusses the dilemma you are facing:  http://blog.scottlogic.com/2008/12/02/wpf-datagrid-detecting-clicked-cell-and-row.html.  He provides examples on how to accomplish the task at hand.

Comment: Thank you very much! This article helps alot :)